Standard deviation on result of calculation
I'm calculating a value based on experimental data. The calculation is
$$ k = \frac{a - b}{c} \cdot \frac{1}{T}, $$
and $a$, $b$ and $c$ are all measured experimentally, multiple times, with some variation between samples, and $T$ is a constant. They are also measured independently, so even if I happen to have $N$ values each of $a$, $b$, and $c$, I cannot say that they "belong" to each other in triples, or anything like that.
What is the correct way of calculating the standard deviation in the result $k$? I believe I can not-totally-unreasonably assume that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are normally distributed, although strictly speaking the numbers are all constrained (both in reality and in the measurements) to be positive, so they are not truly normal.
(I tried calculating $k$ from all permutations of my different values of $a$, $b$, and $c$. Say $N = 4$, then I have $4 \times 4 \times 4 = 64$ different combinations I can use to calculate $k$, and then I can take the standard deviation of that. It feels a bit like a hack, though, so some theoretical insight would be nice.)
Just to provide a more concrete example, here are some numbers (in the form of python code, for convenience). These are obtained from measurements, where the values of $a$ measured from four different samples, $b$ from four other samples, and $c$ from yet another four samples.
a = np.array([286641, 266093, 227900, 165559])
b = np.array([136748, 159846, 108337, 164340])
c = np.array([303791, 327579, 410016, 340820])
T = 5

So the question then becomes: Give these data, and given that $k$ is calculated from the equation above, what, if anything, can I say about the standard deviation (or other ways of communicating uncertainty) in my calculated values of $k$.

If a, b, and c don't necessarily belong together, then how are you doing the calculation? They have to be triples or the formula makes no sense.

The actual situation is a bit involved, so I'll give a simpler example. Say I want to calculate the ratio of the weight of cats and dogs. I measure N dogs, they have different weights, and I measure M cats, and they have different weights. For each pair of dogs and cats, I can calculate the ratio, but what is the correct way to calculate the standard deviation of that ratio?

Okay but this is an example with two random variables and they are pairs which would translate to three random variables that are triples, but you're saying a, b, and c aren't triples?

In the example, they are not pairs in the sense that they belong together. If I weigh 3 dogs and 5 cats, my numbers are just independent samples from two different populations. There is no "natural" way to pair one dog and one cat, but for all possible pairs I can of course calculate a ratio. Similarly, in my case, I have N independent samples from three different populations, from which I can choose any of N^3 different triples, but none of those triples are any more natural than the others.

So, in your toy example, you want the standard deviation of the 27 possible ratios?
I don't think there is an analytic solution to this.

The standard deviation of the 27 ratios in the example I can just calculate, since I have the numbers. My question is about what (if anything) I can say about the standard deviation of k, given my measured values of a, b, and c. I can provide some example numbers in my question, perhaps that will make it more clear what I'm actually after.

I think I found the answer on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_random_variables#Variance_algebra_for_random_variables
If $a$ and $b$ are independent, then the variance of $d = a + b$ is just $\mathrm{var}(a) + \mathrm{var}(b)$.
Next, the variance of $d / c$ is
$$ \mathrm{var}(d/c) = \mathrm{var}(d) \mathrm{var}(1/c) + \mathrm{var}(d) (\mathrm{E}(1/c))^2 + \mathrm{var}(1/c) (\mathrm{E}(d))^2.$$
